# How to filter out light entering bayes filter

Tags: optics

I am trying to run an experiment where I have green fluorescent beads that absorb 490nm light and when excited, emit light at 515nm. Right next to it, I have brilliant blue light that absorbs ~620nm light. When I shine pure 490nm light at it and capture the image and split the image into 3 channels, R,G, and, B, I notice that there is alot of excess light (presumably red light) still passing through the Bayes filter.

Question: How do I capture images to ensure that I capture solely green light and minimize the red light that still enters the camera. I understand that at 515nm, ~2-3% of red light still passes through a CMV4000 lens and I wish to eliminate that.

I'm new to this community and would greatly appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: where does the red light come from?

Comment: It is probably coming from the surrounding environment.

Comment: perhaps the camera red sensor is sensitive to other colors

Comment: is the experiment portable? ... can it be moved into a darkroom?